# How can I use a JSON array generated in PHP in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to use a JSON array generated in a php function in a javascript function. My code is this:

```
$query = "SELECT lat, lng FROM Eventi";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error() . "<br/><br/>" . $query);
if (mysql_affected_rows() != 0) {
     while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows =  array(
           "latitudine" => $r['lat'],
           "longitudine" => $r['lng'],
       );}
       $risultato_rows = json_encode($rows);
```

Now I want to recover them in a subroutine did javascript to use them, and I tried so:

```
var res = JSON.parse($risultato_rows);
    alert var prova = res.[latitudine];
```

This code doesn't work; what can I do to make it function properly?

Comment: Is the first snippet PHP and the second snippet JavaScript? If so, you can't use the same variables directly.

Comment: are you echo? `var res = JSON.parse(<?php echo $risultato_rows?>);` console log after its, `console.log(res);`

Answer (score 2):

```
res.[latitudine];  // You seem to mix up both the
                   // dot and bracket notation..
```

supposed to be either

`res.latitudine;`  **OR**  `res["latitudine"];`

Answer (score 1):

A PHP variable isn't directly visible in Javascript. Supposing you're not doing AJAX but just trying to embedd JSON in your script, you might do this :

```
?><script>
var res = JSON.parse('<?php echo $risultato_rows; ?>');
var prova = res.latitudine;
alert (prova);
</script><?php
```

Comment: One may just echo the JSON directly since JSON is a subset of JavaScript.

Comment: @Asad The keys are always quoted, how does that prevent you from just echoing it.

Comment: I try with:

     var res = JSON.parse('<?php echo $risultato_rows; ?>');
     var prova = res.latitudine;
     alert (prova);

and

     var res = JSON.parse('<?= $risultato_rows; ?>');
     var prova = res.latitudine;
     alert (prova);

but in both case don't work!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You need to `echo` the JSON string that is contained in `$risultato_rows`. That is:

   `var res = JSON.parse('<?= $risultato_rows; ?>');`
2. When accessing properties, you put the key name as a string in the brackets. To access the `latitudine` property, you would use `res.["latitudine"]`
3. The var keyword is used when declaring variables, not when accessing them. Use separate statements to assign the value to `prova` and alert it.

Comment: I try with:

     var res = JSON.parse('<?php echo $risultato_rows; ?>');
     var prova = res.latitudine;
     alert (prova);

and

     var res = JSON.parse('<?= $risultato_rows; ?>');
     var prova = res.latitudine;
     alert (prova);

but in both case don't work!